# How to get price of product in Drupal Commerce using Services module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-services, drupal-commerce

I installed Services Module and REST Server to get list of products and details. I can only get product display nodes and product id,

but how to get product price and availability info from Drupal Commerce.

List of all nodes (including product display nodes)

http://drupalcommerce.myappdemo.com/services/node

Get single product display node
http://drupalcommerce.myappdemo.com/services/node/37

But it does give product id, but not product price.

Please give me an idea how to get one.

Comment: There's a sandbox module called [Commerce Services](http://drupal.org/sandbox/drupalista-br/1283494) which integrates Commerce with Services. That's the closest you'll get without writing it yourself at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this api's it will help you

```
 $order = commerce_cart_order_load($uid);
   // Get the order for user just logged in.
    $order_authenticated = reset(commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array('uid' => $this->store_customer->uid, 'status' => 'cart'), TRUE));
   //update the order status
    $form_state['order'] = commerce_order_status_update($order, 'checkout_checkout', TRUE);
    // Load the order status object for the current order.
    $order_status = commerce_order_status_load($order->status);
    $profile = commerce_customer_profile_load($order->data['profiles'][$checkout_pane['pane_id']]);
    $order = commerce_order_load($order->order_id);
   // Give other modules a chance to alter the order statuses.
    drupal_alter('commerce_order_status_info', $order_statuses);
     $order_state = commerce_order_state_load($order_status['state']);
      // Load the line items for temporary storage in the form array.
    $line_items = commerce_line_item_load_multiple($line_item_ids);
    // load line item
    commerce_line_item_load($line_item_id)
    //load the commerce product
    $product = commerce_product_load($product_id)
     // Load the referenced products.
    $products = commerce_product_load_multiple($product_ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the [Commerce Services](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_services) module.
2. Enable the '**product-display -> retrieve**' and '**product -> retrieve**' resources for your Services endpoint.
3. Do a GET on **?q=my_service_endpoint/product-display/123.json** , this will get the product display information for node 123. This will also contain the ids of the product(s) that are referenced by this node (e.g. product 456), along with the product's price.
4. *Optional*, do a GET on **?q=my_service_endpoint/product/456.json** , this will get more complete product information for the product with id 456.